# Is there any way to make this top-level code synchronous

Tags: javascript, async-await, event-loop

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/AnirudhMS/pen/poRmjao?

Code:

```
console.log('Started script execution.');
(async () => {
  let promiseWrapper = async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Inside async script.");
      Promise.resolve();
    }, 0);
  };
  await promiseWrapper();
})();
console.log('Finished script execution.');
```

Output:

```
Started script execution.
Finished script execution.
Inside async script.
```

Issue:
As can be seen from the above output, in top-level code, the browser does not wait for async operations to finish. Now this also means that an event like `dom-ready` will be fired after the synchronous code has finished executing. <s>The problem is not with the `dom-ready` event exactly but</s> is there a way to ensure that the output is as follows:

```
Started script execution.
Inside async script.
Finished script execution.
```

Edit:
**Note: The solution needs to work if I replace the setTimeout with an await Promise call!!!**

Edit 2:
**The solution needs to be such that the `dom-ready` event or the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired after the execution of the async script. Is that possible?**

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Dominik would the solution you pointed to work in case I wanted to execute a Promise in place of the `setTimeout` ??

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. You have some issue and try to fix it by hacking the system. So what are you trying to do in the first place, and what doesn't work there?

Answer (score 0):

First, you shoud return Promise, not only use `Promise.resolve` inside timeout callback, second, use promise-like variant in top scope:

```
console.log('Started script execution.');
(async () => {
  let promiseWrapper = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Inside async script.");
      res();
    }, 0);
  });
  await promiseWrapper();
})().then(() => {
  console.log('Finished script execution.');
})
```